# Truncated rows in Pandas DF

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv",encoding='latin-1')
```

df:

```
     Text
0 .  I am having a good time on the vacation, but......
```

where I am not able to read the complete sentence. I tried using

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)  
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

still I am facing the issue. Any suggestions please.

Comment: Those options set amounts of rows and columns. This is a single column truncated. Are you using an IDE or a normal shell?

Comment: @kabanus I am using Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Then I think my solution is OK, and the problem is not the IDE.

Comment: @kabanus yep it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the width of a column is not available on all versions of pandas. on the latest (0.23.3) you have:

```
display.max_colwidth
```

as an option, where as stated [in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html):

> The maximum width in characters of a column in the repr of a pandas
>   data structure. When the column overflows, a “…” placeholder is
>   embedded in the output. [default: 50] [currently: 50]

I count 51 by the way in your example.